# SQL transaction not working when initiated via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions, mysqli

I have the following query which does not work when it is initiated by my PHP code:

```
$sql = 'START TRANSACTION;
        DELETE FROM task_actions
            WHERE task_id='.$id.';
        DELETE FROM tasks
            WHERE id='.$id.';
        COMMIT;
       ';
```

When I `echo $sql` and put the output directly into phpMyAdmin, it works without a problem; and when I had it done in two steps instead of one transaction, it worked from my PHP code, too.

I first thought MySQL might not allow transactions, but [stackoverflow.com/questions/2050310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050310) and [stackoverflow.com/questions/2960012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960012) showed that was wrong.

I found I could disable autocommit, do both queries and reactivate autocommit ([stackoverflow.com/a/17607619](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607619) & [stackoverflow.com/a/12092151](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092151)), but I would prefer not to.

Any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: I am not overly familiar with mysqli, but are you using [multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to run these multiple queries at once? From memory, most connections will bork if you try to run multiple queries.

Comment: I was not. You are right and it seems quite logical now I've got the answer and your comment. I'll go back to my original two step implementation - seems shorter and simpler in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'START TRANSACTION';
// run this query
$sql = 'DELETE FROM task_actions WHERE task_id=?';
// run this query
$sql = 'DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=?';
// run this query
$sql = 'COMMIT';
// finally run this one
```